# Show tooltip in column chart when hovering crosshair line

Tags: highcharts

Using Highstock ("StockChart"), the tooltips for each bar in a column chart will show if hovering the "crosshair line" above the actual bar. See this example:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        }]
    });
```

[StockChart JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/column/)

How do I achieve the same result using a Highcharts column chart? An example of a similar Highcharts example column chart can be found here:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            ['Shanghai', 23.7],
            ['Lagos', 16.1],
            ['Instanbul', 14.2],
            ['Karachi', 14.0],
            ['Mumbai', 12.5],
            ['Moscow', 12.1],
            ['São Paulo', 11.8],
            ['Beijing', 11.7],
            ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
            ['Delhi', 11.1],
            ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
            ['Seoul', 10.4],
            ['Jakarta', 10.0],
            ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
            ['Tianjin', 9.3],
            ['Tokyo', 9.0],
            ['Cairo', 8.9],
            ['Dhaka', 8.9],
            ['Mexico City', 8.9],
            ['Lima', 8.9]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

[Column JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/)

As you can see in the second example, the tooltips only show when the actual bars are hovered. I realize I can achieve it by setting "shared" to true for the tooltip, like in this example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
});
```

[Column JSFiddle example using shared tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)

The problem with that solution is that I don't want a shared tooltip, I want one individual tooltip for each bar.

Thank you.

Comment: But options responsible for such behavior is shared tooltip. Why you can't use that option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of really using more than one series when using shared tooltip. The tooltip can be 'shared by itself' and you achieve the result you need ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc0hoLfx/)). Simply adding the tooltip configs of your third example in your second do the trick.

```
tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
```

Comment: But how I configure it if I want the third type of chart (multiple series), but a single tooltip for each bar? As I wrote I don't aim to have a shared tooltip for all the bars in a category.